# How to build a decision table with "NOT IN (a,b,c)" logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, rules, business-logic

Suppose there is a business rule used to derive a value and due to how the business users need to update this, the logic must be held in a table and not a function.

Example of current function

```
 WHEN inputA IN (1,2,3) AND inputB NOT IN (55,66) THEN OUTPUT = 'HQ'
 WHEN inputA IN (3,6)   AND inputB     IN (27,44) THEN OUTPUT = 'Northern'
 WHEN inputC IN (6,4,1) AND inputB NOT IN (55,66) THEN OUTPUT = 'Eastern'
 etc.
```

I can build a table with a row for each combination
e.g.

| OUTPUT | A val | B val | C val | D val | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Northern | 3 | 27 |  |  |  |
| Northern | 3 | 44 |  |  |  |
| Northern | 6 | 27 |  |  |  |
| Northern | 6 | 44 |  |  |  |

How then to model the "NOT IN" part of this?

Surely there is a way where I do not have to create all the 'exception' rows that would potentially need to be updated based on changing reference data?

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of input columns?

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to represent these expressions?

Comment: you can add extra column for each A , B  and C called like 'A operator' and set it as "=" or "<>" .  its the only solution i can think of to apply these rules on a table

Comment: This actually looks similar to a problem a colleague of mine had the other week, but with the added complexity of additional arbitrary columns. I might be able to bend what I did there, as I still have the script, but some meaningful sample data and expected results will be really useful if I'm going to entertain that.

Comment: It is likely that the number of input columns will not exceed 5

Comment: So it *could*? The way you word that suggests that the columns need to be dynamic; if so then you're in for a world of hurt. If that is the case then a fundamental redesign is likely in order.

Comment: @AliFidanli just wondering if there will be a logic conflict when JOINing on these in this manner  (f=fact table, r=rules table) e.g.  .. FROM f JOIN r ON ( f.aVal = r.aVal ) AND ( aVal <> r.aNotVal ) AND ( f.bVal = r.bVal ) AND ( r.val <> bNotVal )..etc.

Comment: @Larnu I just had a quick check of the function and in total there are a mixture of 8 attributes, however, in any given "WHEN" there only appear to be a max of 3 (of the 8) attributes used. In total there are around 15 WHENs

Comment: @ScottHunter the users will not have access to the DB and could break a function if they're allowed edit rights. It has been decided they will edit the 'rules' via an existing app with grid edit capabilities and audit/checks.

Comment: You have a set of rules defined in an "intensive definition" and you are trying to convert it to an "extensive definition". It's possible to do that in a single set for the `IN` part, but not with `NOT IN` part. Now, you can produce a more complex model (separate tables, or expression assembling) to model these rules, but it won't be as direct as you probably want.

Comment: In what way does that answer my question?

Comment: @ScottHunter misunderstood...I just need to represent the function as a table

Answer (score 1):

You could represent these expressions w/ a table where each row contained:

- Output
- Equals? (true or false)
- Input
- Value

which would represent "If (INPUT = VALUE) = EQUALS? then OUTPUT", except that you only need 1 satisfying row for a given OUTPUT/INPUT where EQUALS? is true, but all rows must be satisfied where EQUALS? is false.

This assumes your have only one "rule" for each distinct output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at using a rule table with positive and negative rules.

The rule table stores the valids as integers, but the invalids in a string with delimiters. (not sure if json or xml would be better)

But having negative rules makes it really tricky.
Because it's easy to ignore a rule by adding another for the same output name.

Personally I think it's safer to use a UDF for this type of rules.

> ```
> create table test (
>  id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
>  inputA int, 
>  inputB int, 
>  inputC int
> )
>
> create table output_areas (
>  code varchar(2) primary key, 
>  name varchar(30) not null
> )
>
> insert into output_areas values
>   ('HQ', 'HQ')
> , ('N', 'Northern'), ('E', 'Eastern')
> , ('W', 'Westhern'), ('S', 'Southern')
> , ('X', 'Extern'), ('Z', 'The Zone')
>
>
> create table input_rules (
>  id int identity(1,1) primary key, 
>  output_area_code varchar(2) not null,
>  relevance int not null default 0,
>  inputA_valid int,
>  inputB_valid int,
>  inputC_valid int, 
>  inputA_invalid varchar(100),
>  inputB_invalid varchar(100),
>  inputC_invalid varchar(100),
>  foreign key (output_area_code) references output_areas(code)
> )
>
>
> insert into input_rules (output_area_code, relevance) 
> values ('X', 0);
>
> insert into input_rules (output_area_code, relevance, inputA_valid) 
> values ('Z',10, 1);
>
> insert into input_rules (output_area_code, relevance, inputA_valid, inputB_invalid) 
> values
>   ('HQ', 20, 1, '|55|56|')
> , ('HQ', 20, 2, '|55|56|')
> , ('HQ', 20, 3, '|55|56|')
> ;
> insert into input_rules (output_area_code, relevance, inputA_valid, inputB_valid) 
> values
>   ('N', 30, 3, 27), ('N', 30, 3, 44)
> , ('N', 30, 6, 27), ('N', 30, 6, 44)
> ;
> insert into input_rules (output_area_code, relevance, inputC_valid, inputB_invalid) 
> values
>   ('E', 20, 6, '|55|66|' )
> , ('E', 20, 4, '|55|66|' )
> ;
>
>
> insert into test 
>   (inputA, inputB, inputC) values 
>   (1, 56, null)
> , (3, 44, null), (3, 66, null)
> , (1, 66, null), (1, 88, null)
> , (null, 66, 6), (null, 88, 6)
> ```

> ```
> select * from input_rules
> ```
>
> ```
> id | output_area_code | relevance | inputA_valid | inputB_valid | inputC_valid | inputA_invalid | inputB_invalid | inputC_invalid
> -: | :--------------- | --------: | -----------: | -----------: | -----------: | :------------- | :------------- | :-------------
>  1 | X                |         0 |         null |         null |         null | null           | null           | null          
>  2 | Z                |        10 |            1 |         null |         null | null           | null           | null          
>  3 | HQ               |        20 |            1 |         null |         null | null           | |55|56|        | null          
>  4 | HQ               |        20 |            2 |         null |         null | null           | |55|56|        | null          
>  5 | HQ               |        20 |            3 |         null |         null | null           | |55|56|        | null          
>  6 | N                |        30 |            3 |           27 |         null | null           | null           | null          
>  7 | N                |        30 |            3 |           44 |         null | null           | null           | null          
>  8 | N                |        30 |            6 |           27 |         null | null           | null           | null          
>  9 | N                |        30 |            6 |           44 |         null | null           | null           | null          
> 10 | E                |        20 |         null |         null |            6 | null           | |55|66|        | null          
> 11 | E                |        20 |         null |         null |            4 | null           | |55|66|        | null
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from test t
> outer apply (
>   select top 1 ref.name as output
>   from input_rules r
>   join output_areas ref on ref.code = r.output_area_code
>   where (r.inputA_valid is null or r.inputA_valid = t.inputA) 
>     and (r.inputB_valid is null or r.inputB_valid = t.inputB) 
>     and (r.inputC_valid is null or r.inputC_valid = t.inputC)
>     and (r.inputA_invalid is null or r.inputA_invalid not like concat('%|', t.inputA, '|%')) 
>     and (r.inputB_invalid is null or r.inputB_invalid not like concat('%|', t.inputB, '|%')) 
>     and (r.inputC_invalid is null or r.inputC_invalid not like concat('%|', t.inputC, '|%')) 
>   order by r.relevance desc, r.output_area_code asc
> ) ca
> ```
>
> ```
> id | inputA | inputB | inputC | output  
> -: | -----: | -----: | -----: | :-------
>  1 |      1 |     56 |   null | The Zone
>  2 |      3 |     44 |   null | Northern
>  3 |      3 |     66 |   null | HQ      
>  4 |      1 |     66 |   null | HQ      
>  5 |      1 |     88 |   null | HQ      
>  6 |   null |     66 |      6 | Extern  
>  7 |   null |     88 |      6 | Eastern
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33489cc8181dcf184f97b35970009443)*